# Replace uppercase acronym with its full text lowercase *except* when in a Headline Case Sentence

Tags: javascript, string

I want to replace an always uppercase acronym (e.g. "What is your ***IP*** address") with its lowercase full text ("What is your ***internet protocol*** address") **unless** it has been used in a sentence that's in headline case, in which case I want to also make the acronym headline case ("What Is Your ***Internet Protocol*** Address?").

The fact that the target for replacement is always an uppercase acronym makes this more complicated that a simple substitution like [cloud-to-butt](https://github.com/panicsteve/cloud-to-butt).

I'll be doing this in Javascript as a browser plugin, so I don't want it to be super slow.

I can think of a couple pretty gross, awkward hacks to maybe make this work, but if anyone has anything more elegant, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript replace function to replace the string, and do some few checking to make sure it has not been used in header.